# Can I calculate the change of the bicycle's modal share from marginal effects obtained by logistic regression?

Tags: regression, logistic, marginal-effect

I want/need to analyse the influence of certain parameters on the share of cycling in the total number of trips.

What I have is a database of more than 960,000 trips within Germany in 2017, containing:

- Trip data: length, mode of transport, weather, purpose, ...
- Personal data: age, attitudes, access to car (y/n), driving license
  (y/n), ...
- Data about the county where the trip started: rural/urban, traffic
  density, cycling infrastructure, topography, share of students, ...

My dependent variable is: "was this trip made by bike? (y/n)".

I did a logistic regression and calculated the marginal effects. So I know the influence (if significant) of some variables on the **propability** that a trip is made by bike.

**My question now is: Can I somehow deduce from this the influence of certain developments (e.g. more bicycle infrastructure, less car ownership, ...) on the current share of cycling in total traffic?**

If yes, under which circumstances?

Thank you in advance for your support!